# Best way to integrate ads into a single-page app that uses Dart?

Tags: dart, adsense

If I am building a single page app with multiple screens, is it possible to use something like AdSense or another similar ad network in my screens? I tried dropping in some code but it either creates a javascript error on run or doesn't show anything...

Comment: Can you please add the code you dropped in and what error you got.

Comment: I fiddled with it a bit more today and got to the point where now I'm just getting "Uncaught Error: Cannot find a responsive size for a container of width=0px and data-ad-format=auto" I'm assuming from the adsense JS. I'm using the responsive adsense ad code and have tried it in an unstyled div and a sized div...

Comment: Just not enough information what you are actually trying. Words are cheap, show some code ;-)

Comment: I'm probably going to switch to size ads so don't really worry about it but literally I was just using cut and pasted adsense code into a div:

    <div style="width:100%;height:300px" id="adsense"><script async="" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">      </script>
    <!-- Tennis Sim -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx" data-ad-format="auto" data-adsbygoogle-status="done"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script></div>

Comment: Should work. Are you using Polymer (shadow DOM) ?